# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. HOW TO FIX IT

Tags: androidx

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.Omid found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.ScriptInjector found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.a found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.AdEvents found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.AdSession found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.AdSessionConfiguration found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.AdSessionContext found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.AdSessionContextType found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.CreativeType found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.ErrorType found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.FriendlyObstructionPurpose found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.ImpressionType found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.Owner found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.Partner found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.VerificationScriptResource found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.a found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.media.InteractionType found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.media.MediaEvents found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.media.PlayerState found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.media.Position found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.adsession.media.VastProperties found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.b found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.c found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.publisher.AdSessionStatePublisher found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.publisher.AdSessionStatePublisher$a found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.publisher.a found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.publisher.b found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.walking.TreeWalker found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.walking.TreeWalker$TreeWalkerNanoTimeLogger found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.walking.TreeWalker$TreeWalkerTimeLogger found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.walking.a found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.walking.a$a found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.walking.b found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-runtime (com.vungle:vungle-ads:7.1.0)
> Duplicate class com.iab.omid.library.vungle.walking.c found in modules jetified-publisher-sdk-android-6.12.1-runtime (com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.12.1) and jetified-vungle-ads-7.1.0-run

SOLV THIS PROBLEM......................................................................................................................

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).